# Adding a parent element to existing elements using XDocument, XMLDocument or XPath?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

For the following problem, which API requires less code,  XMLDocument or XDoc? Is there any other approach besides XMLDocument, XDoc or XPath that is more suitable for this task? (Ignoring performance and file sizes are small)

Trying to turn some elements into a child of a node that that appear in the list e.g. (the indentation is not important, please ignore it)

```
<PersonList>
  <Person>
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <LName>LName1</LName>
    <Phone>Phone</Phone>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Name2</Name>
    <LName>LName2</LName>
    <Phone>Phone2</Phone>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Name3</Name>
    <LName>LName3</LName>
    <Phone>Phone3</Phone>
  </Person>
</PersonList>
```

I am trying to turn them into  this

```
<PersonList>
  <Person>
    <PersonDetailsList>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
      <LName>LName1</LName>
      <Phone>Phone</Phone>
    </PersonDetailsList>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonDetailsList>
      <Name>Name2</Name>
      <LName>LName2</LName>
      <Phone>Phone2</Phone>
    </PersonDetailsList>
  </Person>
    <Person>
      <PersonDetailsList>
        <Name>Name3</Name>
        <LName>LName3</LName>
        <Phone>Phone3</Phone>
      </PersonDetailsList>
  </Person>
</PersonList>
```

Comment: Without some value system defined, "better" is quite meaningless to an engineer. Perhaps you could be more specific, e.g. "better with respect to performance" or "better with respect with compatibility." Otherwise the answer is purely a matter of opinion.

Comment: @JohnWu : Yes, changing it to which way would be shorter, ignoring the performance and large amounts to be transformed.

Comment: @JohnWu : Actually with XPath that might be a trivial task, requiring far less programming than either of XDoc or XMLDocument approach.

Comment: Personally I would probably deserialize the list, map it to a different list, and serialize it. That would result in the most readable, maintainable code, IMO. But it might not be the shortest.

Comment: @JohnWu : if it is straight forward I go for it, been wrestling with errors, XML is not something I do often and most likely wont be doing it again for another few years, happy to take simple straight forward approach that just works for simple test data in this question or anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xml Linq works very well :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> people = doc.Descendants("Person").ToList();
            foreach (XElement person in people)
            {
                var children = person.Nodes().ToList();
                person.ReplaceWith(new XElement("Person", new object[] {
                    new XElement("PersonDetailsList", children)
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add parent node

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var elems = doc.Descendants("Person");
foreach (XElement elem in elems)
{
    elem.ReplaceWith(new XElement("PersonDetailsList", elem));
}
```